# Using ngFor in NativeScript + Angula2 application

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to show a list of labels with ngFor.
BELTS is a simple data structure. each item in it have a subject.

I'm getting an error:
JS: Error: Error in ./SilabusComponent class SilabusComponent - inline template:2:64 caused by: 
Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined.

seems that it doesn't know item. any idea?

following is the component decoretor:

```
@Component({
   selector: "kbm-silabus",
   template: `
      <StackLayout>
        <Label ngFor="let item of silabusList; let i=index"                    [text]="item.subject"></Label> 
    </StackLayout>
   `
})

export class SilabusComponent {
    private sub: any;
    silabusList: Array<Silabus>;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.page.actionBar.title = "KBM School";
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.silabusList = [];
        this.silabusSubjects = [];

        BELTS[this.id].silabus.forEach((item, index) => {
            this.silabusList.push(new Silabus(item.subject, item.content));
            console.log(item.subject);
        })
      });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: In this repo - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-directives/ngfor-items you could find sample example, how to use ngFor directive in NativeScript Angular2 project

Answer (score 4):

You have missed the asterisk sign in front of ngFor, which is very important as otherwise, you can only apply ngFor for templates with its full syntax. In NativeScript projects use the ***ngFor** syntax.

e.g.

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of silabusList">
   <Label [text]="item.subject"></Label> 
</StackLayout>
```

Basically, this is how to achive the same output with the different syntax rules:

```
<!-- Examples (A) and (B) are the same -->

<!-- (A) *ngFor -->
<Label *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [text]="hero"></Label >

<!-- (B) ngFor with template -->
<template ngFor let-hero [ngForOf]="heroes">
  <Label [text]="hero"></Label >
</template>
```